# Getting many syntax errors in my PHP code

Tags: php

This is my code. I am getting errors every time the page loads and I don't know what is wrong. If you could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
include ('steamauth/userInfo.php');
$myfile = fopen("userid.txt", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
    if( strpos(file_get_contents("/userid.txt"),$_GET[$steamprofile['steamid']]) !== false){
        fwrite($myfile,$steamprofile['steamid']);}
        fclose($myfile)
    else( strpos(file_get_contents("/userid.txt"),$_GET[$steamprofile['steamid']]) !== true){
        fclose($myfile)
        echo"<html lang="en-US">
             <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://example.com">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                     window.location.href = "http://example.com"
                </script>
                <title>Page Redirection</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>If you are not redirected automatically, follow the <a href="http://example.com">link to www.example.com</a></p>
            </body>
            </html>";}
?>
```

Here are the errors:

```
 [25-Apr-2015 09:46:38 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in /example.com/userid.php on line 4
 [25-Apr-2015 09:47:42 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in /example.com/userid.php on line 4
 [25-Apr-2015 09:48:09 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ']' in /example.com/userid.php on line 4
 [25-Apr-2015 09:48:40 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /example.com/userid.php on line 7
 [25-Apr-2015 09:49:37 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /example.com/userid.php on line 7
 [25-Apr-2015 09:50:17 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in /example.com/userid.php on line 7
 [25-Apr-2015 09:51:06 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSEIF in /example.com/userid.php on line 7
 [25-Apr-2015 09:53:07 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /example.com/userid.php on line 6
 [25-Apr-2015 09:55:06 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /example.com/userid.php on line 6
 [25-Apr-2015 09:55:34 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '}' in /example.com/userid.php on line 6
 [25-Apr-2015 09:56:53 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ')' in /example.com/userid.php on line 7
 [25-Apr-2015 09:57:15 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /example.com/userid.php on line 8
 [25-Apr-2015 09:58:19 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /example.com/userid.php on line 8
 [25-Apr-2015 09:59:23 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /example.com/userid.php on line 8
 [25-Apr-2015 10:00:02 Australia/Perth] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /example.com/userid.php on line 8
```

There are more (10 MB error log more), but these are the most recent and every time I change some new errors appear.

The code is supposed to open a file (userid.txt) then check if that file contains their steamid if it doesn't it writes in it, if it does then it redirects away.

Comment: share those (parse) errors, obvious they are.

Comment: Nobody can provide advise unless you go into detail about errors, what the code is supposed to do, or previous debugging steps. (And question titles should be technical summaries, not bore the audience.)

Comment: check echo string you use " inside "

Comment: yeah, knew it; parse errors. question's off-topic, it's time you learn how to debug code

Comment: read the manual on strings https://php.net/language.types.string and echo http://php.net/echo

Comment: seems like a beginner ..!!

Comment: why is this off topic? The guy is a new poster, and it would be tedious for him to post this topic for each error he has. My reply below clearly (albeit briefly) addresses each error . The code the OP states does include all the error code referenced in his error log as well as the error log itself. I have reworded the title to be (A bit) more useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no idea, then at least Google search the type and name of the error - the error log does give you plenty enough information to solve your error. +1 for using the error log, -1 for not actually reading and using the information it gives you.

To give some more detail: the core of your errors is that you're not writing the PHP correctly, so this implies you don't know PHP, so really what you should be doing is not running before you can crawl and going away and reading up all about PHP and the structure and layout and methods behind the language and how to get intended results from the code you write.

Pretty much all your errors are down to bad syntax, I could rewrite the whole code block for you and format it correctly but really I think it's better for you to go away and read about [how to structure IF statements](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php), [how to use `strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) and [how to open and edit files](https://www.developphp.com/page.php?id=237) as starting points. 
Also read up about [how to structure arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and google search info on how to structure Multidimensional arrays (as that's another syntax fault in your code).

And seriously, I do mean well done for using the error log. Many programmers in PHP merrily get things mostly working and completely ignore learning how to detect and collect their non-critical errors.

## Some further pointers to this specific code:

- check each instruction ends with a `;`
- check the difference between `$_GET` and `$_POST`, read about them in php.net, also read about what these identifiers actually are (they're special).
- be careful with `print` and `echo` statements that the character they open with (`"` or `'`) is escaped (*ie preceded by a backslash*) if found *inside* the string.
- check that [multidimensional arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp) are structured correctly - `$array[0][1]` NOT `$array[0[1]]`
- check the URL to the files you want to use is correct.
- Eat 5 different pieces of fruit or veg *a day*

Comment: Thankyou, I am very new to this and this is the only php I have got to do for the whole of my site. It is just my hobby and you are right I don't really know what I am doing. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though :). 

Edit: I should have mentioned I don't know what the errors mean and how to fix them myself. I have 0 formal education in any programming languages and everything I have learnt is self taught.

Comment: it's ok. http://PHP.net is your friend, it is an excellent reference site, although I'd suggest wider google searches for tutorials etc. on specific actions (like opening files, etc) .